# Reading a Gephi graph in R

Tags: r, graph, package, gephi

I would need to read a Gephi graph into Rstudio. To do the contrary - reading a R graph into Gephi - I found the rgexf package and the write.gexf function. But there is apprently not a read.gexf :)

Do anyone have a solution to this little issue ?

Sincerely yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://blog.gephi.org/2013/rgexf-an-r-library-to-work-with-gexf-graph-files/ on this page you have an example from **rgexf** package:

```
# Installing from CRAN and loading
install.packages("rgexf", dependencies=TRUE)
library(rgexf)

# Reading lesmiserables graph (and summarizing)
lesmiserables <- read.gexf("http://gephi.org/datasets/LesMiserables.gexf")
summary(lesmiserables)
```

So - `read.gexf()` should be an answer to your problems;)

Homepage of this package - https://bitbucket.org/gvegayon/rgexf/wiki/Home